# How to read and print hexadecimal numbers from a file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read 14 digit long hexadecimal numbers from a file and then print them. My idea is to use a long long int and read the lines from the files with fscanf as if they were strings and then turn the string into a hex number using atoll. The problem is I am getting a seg value on my fscanf line according to valgrind and I have absolutely no idea why. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

if(argc != 2){
    printf("error argc!= 2\n");
    return 0;
   }

char *fileName = argv[1];    
FILE *fp = fopen( fileName, "r");

if(fp == NULL){
   return 0;
}

long long int num;
char *line;

while( fscanf(fp, "%s", line) == 1 ){
    num = atoll(line);
    printf("%x\n", num);
 }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: you're not allocating any space for `line`.

Comment: try `char line[1024]; while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL) {..}` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `line` variable is not initialized, so when `fscanf()` dereferences it you get undefined behavior.

You should use:

```
char line[1024];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
```

To do the loading.

If you're on C99, you might want to use `uint64_t` to hold the number, since that makes it clear that 14-digit hexadecimal numbers (4 * 14 = 56) will fit.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want to read your numbers as character strings? Why not allow the `scanf` do the work for you?

```
long long int  num;

while( fscanf(fp, "%llx", &num) == 1 ){  // read  a long long int in hex
    printf("%llx\n", num);               // print a long long int in hex
}
```

BTW, note the `ll` size specifier to `%x` conversion in `printf` - it defines the integer value will be of `long long` type.

*Edit*
Here is a simple example of two loops reading a 3-line input (with two, no and three numbers in consecutive lines) with a 'hex int' format and with a 'string' format:
    http://ideone.com/ntzKEi
A call to `rewind` allows the second loop read the same input data.

Comment: @davmac Not sure about that. Scanf functions scan `%s` till the first white character; if there are multiple words, numbers or other 'black strings' in a line, the loop should read them all, one by one. There is no code here to discard the rest of input line after the first number.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but I want to clarify the actual reason for the crash you are seeing. The problem is that:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", line)
```

... essentially means "read a string from a file, and store it in the buffer pointed at by `line`". In this case, your `line` variable hasn't been initialised, so it doesn't point anywhere. Technically, this is undefined behavior; in practice, the result will often be that you write over some arbitrary location in your process's address space; furthermore, since it will often point at an illegal address, the operating system can detect and report it as a segment violation or similar, as you are indeed seeing.

Note that `fscanf` with a `%s` conversion will not necessarily read a whole line - it reads a string delimited by whitespace. It might skip lines if they are empty and it might read multiple strings from a single line. This might not matter if you know the precise format of the input file (and it always has one value per line, for instance).

Although it appears in that case that you can probably just use an appropriate modifier to read a hexadecimal number (`fscanf(fp, "%llx", &num)`), rather than read a string and try to do a conversion, there are various situations where you do need to read strings and especially whole lines. There are various solutions to that problem, depending on what platform you are on. If it's a GNU system (generally including Linux) and you don't care about portability, you could use the `m` modifier, and change `line` to `&line`:

```
fscanf(fp, "%ms", &line);
```

This passes a pointer to `line` to `fscanf`, rather than its value (which is uninitialised), and the `m` causes `fscanf` to allocate a buffer and store its address in `line`. You then should `free` the buffer when you are done with it. Check the Glibc manual for details. The nice thing about this approach is that you do not need to know the line length beforehand.

If you are not using a GNU system or you do care about portability, use `fgets` instead of `fscanf` - this is more direct and allows you to limit the length of the line read, meaning that you won't overflow a fixed buffer - just be aware that it will read a whole line at a time, unlike `fscanf`, as discussed above. You should declare `line` as a `char`-array rather than a `char *` and choose a suitable size for it. (Note that you can also specify a "maximum field width" for `fscanf`, eg `fscanf(fp, "%1000s", line)`, but you really might as well use `fgets`).